# NGINX not loading external css file

Tags: html, css, nginx

I created a test html page, inline javascript and css is working fine. But when an external css sheet is referenced, it doesn't seem to load.

**/var/www/ME/test.html**

```
    <html>
            <head>
                    <link href="/test.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
            </head>

            <body onload="javascript:alert('test');">
                    <div class="test">
                            <h1>Hi my name is tzvi</h1>
                    </div>
            </body>
    </html>
```

**/var/www/ME/test.css**

```
    .test {
            color:"red";
    }
```

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
    user www-data;
    worker_processes 4;
    pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

    events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
    }

    http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type text/html;

    server {
            listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
            listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

            error_log /var/log/nginx/file.log warn;

            root /var/www/ME;
            index index.php;

            server_name localhost;

            location / {
                            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
                            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
                            error_log /var/log/nginx/test.log warn;
            }

            location ~ \.php$ {
                            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                            # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
                            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                            fastcgi_index index.php;
                            include fastcgi_params;
            }
    }
    }
```

When I go to `http://<webserver>/test.html` I get the javascript popup, and the text in black. If the css would be working, the text should be red.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried loading the css url directly in the browser to see if the file downloads correctly ?

Comment: @StephaneRolland it loads the css files text. Is it supposed to download rather than display? Thanks for the response

Comment: if it loads the css file, then it's more than probable that the css is accessible when you load the html file. Only case I see where the css could be blocked is a cross domain reference i.e. if your css file came from another server.

Comment: remove the double quotes arround the color name in your css file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the css file to

```
  .test {
            color:red;
    }
```

you should indicate the color name in the css without surrounding doubles quotes `""`.