# CSS not loading for self-hosted Nginx with Jekyll /Hugo site

Tags: css, nginx

I am building a static website on my Olimex Lime2 board (Armbian OS) using Nginx as my webserver. My problem that no matter what static site builder or theme I use, when I go to view the public site, there is no CSS styling. Here is the public site: https://natehn.com

I have tried several themes on Hugo and Jekyll, with little or no modification to the default settings. This is why I think the issue is with Nginx.

I have explored [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222877/nginx-not-loading-external-css-file) and done plenty of Googling but was unable to determine a solution. I'm self-taught and don't know what I am looking for. Hopefully I missed something simple and this is an easy fix.

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
events {}

# Expires map
http {
        map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
                default                    off;
                text/html                  7d;
                text/css                   max;
                application/javascript     max;
                ~image/                    max;
        }


server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  natehn.com;

    location / {
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}

server{
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name natehn.com;

        charset UTF-8; #improve page speed by sending the charset with the first response.

        location / {
        root /home/nathan/blog/public;
        index index.html;
        autoindex off
        }


        #Caching (save html pages for 7 days, rest as long as possible, no caching on frontpage)
        expires $expires;

        location @index {
            add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
            add_header Cache-Control 'no-cache, no-store';
            etag off;
            expires off;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        #location = /50x.html {
        #    root   /var/www/;
        #}

        #Compression

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        # Logs
        access_log   /var/log/nginx/natehn.com.com_ssl.access.log;
        error_log    /var/log/nginx/natehn.com_ssl.error.log;

        # SSL Settings:
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/natehn.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/natehn.com/privkey.pem;

        # Improve HTTPS performance with session resumption
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;

        # Enable server-side protection against BEAST attacks
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

        # Disable SSLv3
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

        # Lower the buffer size to increase TTFB
        ssl_buffer_size 4k;

        #CAUSED ERROR
        # Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites
        # $ sudo openssl dhparam -out /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem 4096
        #ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

        # Enable HSTS (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";

        # Enable OCSP stapling (http://blog.mozilla.org/security/2013/07/29/ocsp-stapling-in-firefox)
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/natehn.com/fullchain.pem;
        resolver 192.34.59.80 66.70.228.164 valid=300s;
        resolver_timeout 5s;
}
}
```

And here is my sites-available/natehn.com, which is linked to sites-enabled:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;


        root /home/nathan/blog/public;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index.html;

        server_name natehn.com www.natehn.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

}
```

I have explored everything I know. Any tips on where to look for potential solutions? Let me know if there is something else you need to look at.

Many thanks :) N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The css link has been blocked because of [mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content) - the page is loaded over **https://** but the href for the css is plain **http://**

Same will be true for your favicon etc.

As a general approach, to use the same protocol as the parent page, simply miss that off the href, for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//natehn.com/css/style-white.css">
```

Edit: Better solution for site builders is to set the base URL to make sure constructed hrefs always use the correct protocol, https in your case:

- For Hugo, see `baseURL` in https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration/
- For Jekyll, see `baseurl` in https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/options/

Wordpress and others have similar options.

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you so much!! This edit to my index.html works for the homepage. It looks like I will need to do this manually every time I have Hugo/Jekyll build the site. Is that the case? And how can I make this change for the whole site, so that none of the content is unsecure?

Comment: I don't know Hugo/Jekyll, but things like Wordpress have a setting for the stem of your external web address.  They often need this to be able to build URLs and can't necessarily tell what the address should be.  It may be that you can simply tell your builder to use `https://natehn.com/` and that will fix it for all hrefs across the site in one go.

Comment: In fact, for Hugo it looks like you need to change the `baseURL` described in https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration/, and for Jekyll it looks like the `baseurl` mentioned in https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/options/

Comment: Thank you so much @randomsock. I thought I had done this, but I guess I had not. I'm a bit of a novice, and I truly appreciate your assistance with this.

Comment: It's all good - we're all in this together :)  Just keep going